# How to convert a huge .csv file to excel using POI

Tags: java, excel, csv, apache-poi

I have Java code that converts CSV to xlsx.  It works fine with a small file size.  Now I  have a CSV file with 2 lakh records (200,000) and on conversion I am getting an out of memory error.

I tried changing the workbook to SXSSFWorkbook and increasing the heap size and Java memory size to -Xms8G -Xmx10G.  Even this did not work.  I tried it on a UNIX box.

On searching, I got some code about using BigGridDemo.  Can anyone help me in customizing that to reading a .csv file and then using its logic to write to xlsx, or any other  solution?

```
     try  {   FileReader input = new FileReader(strFileToConvert);
     BufferedReader bufIn = new BufferedReader(input);  
     if(strExcel_Typ.equals("-xls"))
     {
       wbAll = new HSSFWorkbook();
     }
     else
     {
        wbAll = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
        wbAll.setCompressTempFiles(true);
     }
     sheetAll     = wbAll.createSheet();
     rowAll       = null;
     cellAll      = null;
     shoRowNumAll = 0;

     // do buffered reading from a file
     while ((line = bufIn.readLine()) != null)
     {
        intCntr++;
        //if there is any data in the line
        if (line.length() > 0)
        {
            System.out.println(shoRowNumAll);
           //create a new row on the spreadsheet
           rowAll = sheetAll.createRow((int)shoRowNumAll);
           shoRowNumAll++;

           if (line.indexOf("\"", 0) > 0)
           {
              if (intCntr == 1)
              {
                 //only issue the message the first time quotes are found
                 System.out.println("Double quotes found.  Stripping double quotes from file");
              }

              line = line.replaceAll("\"", "");
           }

           //if its the first row and no delimiters found, there is a problem
           if (line.indexOf(strDelim, 0) == -1  && intCntr == 1)
           {
                System.exit(1);
                   }

           processLine(line);
           ((SXSSFSheet) sheetAll).flushRows(100);
        }
     }
    bufIn.close();
    /write the excel file
     try
     {            String file = strOutPutFile;
                ExcelOutAll  = new FileOutputStream(file);
        wbAll.write(ExcelOutAll);
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
       System.err.println(e.toString());
     }

     ExcelOutAll.close();
```

Processline Method:

```
processLine(String line)
{

  //find the first next delimiter starting in position 0
  intNxtComma = line.indexOf(strDelim, 0);
   while (intCurPosInLine < line.trim().replaceAll(",","").length())
  {
     strCellContent = line.substring((intCurPosInLine), intNxtComma);

     //create a new cell on the new row
     cellAll = rowAll.createCell(intCellNum);


     //set the font defaults
     Font font_couriernew_10 = wbAll.createFont();
     font_couriernew_10.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);
     font_couriernew_10.setFontName("Courier New");

    CellStyle cellStyle = wbAll.createCellStyle();

     //if its the first row, center the text
     if (shoRowNumAll == 1)
     {
        cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        font_couriernew_10.setBoldweight(XSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
     }

     cellStyle.setFont(font_couriernew_10);


     // if the col. needs to be numeric, set the cell format to number
     if ((strNumericCols.indexOf(Integer.toString(intCellNum), 0) > -1) && (intCntr > 1))
     {
        DataFormat datafrmt = wbAll.createDataFormat();
        cellStyle.setDataFormat(datafrmt.getFormat("$#,##0.00"));

        }

     cellAll.setCellStyle(cellStyle);



     //populate the cell
     if ((strNumericCols.indexOf(Integer.toString(intCellNum), 0) > -1) && (intCntr > 1))
     {
        //if the col. needs to be numeric populate with a number
         if(strCellContent != null &&  !"".equals(strCellContent.trim())){
        douCellContent = Double.parseDouble(strCellContent.replaceAll(",",""));
        cellAll.setCellValue(douCellContent);
         }
     }
     else
     {
        cellAll.setCellValue(strCellContent.trim());
     }

     intCellNum++;


     intCurPosInLine = intNxtComma + 1;

     //if we dont find anymore delimiters, set the variable to the line length
     if (line.indexOf(strDelim, intCurPosInLine) == -1)
     {
        intNxtComma = line.trim().length();
     }
     else
     {
        intNxtComma = line.indexOf(strDelim, intNxtComma + 1);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code (the one working with small files)

Comment: You could save the CSV as `.xls`; then it will be correctly opened by Excel. Not nice though.

Comment: Create your `CellStyle` objects outside of your `while` loop so you can reuse them inside as appropriate.

Comment: SXSSFWorkbook ought to be fine in a low memory environment, are you sure it was still giving issues?

Comment: yes its having  problems i changed the code moved the the cellstyle object outside the while loop still  it  processes 50k records and then out of memory occurs.

Comment: JVMDUMP013I Processed dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError".
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Attach handler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.oti.util.Msg (initialization failure)   at
java.lang.String.<init>(String.java     at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140):
298) at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:772)

Comment: at java.util.Properties.  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:766)load
(Properties.java:4      at java.lang.Thread.uncaughtException(Thread.java:1213)1
7Caused by: )java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:28 at 0java.lang.String).
<init>  at (com.ibm.oti.vm.MsgHelp.String.javaloadMessages:(2MsgHelp.java9:81)2
8       at )java.util.Properties
.       at loadcom.ibm.oti.util.PriviAction.(runProperties.java(:PriviAction.java4:1175)5
)

Comment: at java.util.Properties  at java.security.AccessController..loaddoPrivileged((Properties.javaAccessController.java::228002))
        at      at com.ibm.oti.util.Msgcom.ibm.oti.vm.MsgHelp..<clinit>loadMessages((Msg.javaMsgHelp.java::4162)8
        at )java.lang.J9VMInternals
.       at initializeImplcom.ibm.oti.util.PriviAction(Native Method).run     at (java.lang.J9VMInternalsPriviAction.java.:initialize1(J9VMInternals.java5:52)0
0       at )
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.java.security.AccessControlleruncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:772)

Comment: at .java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:766)
doPrivileged    at java.lang.Thread.(AccessController.javauncaughtException:202)
        at com.ibm.oti.util.Msg.<clinit>(Thread.java:12(Msg.java:46)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl13)
(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
        ... 3 more

Comment: any one  any  suggestions  i am  still  not  able  to fix  the issues